# canvas transformation after the path has been defined and recent update of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, width, line, transformation

edit2:

The unwanted behavior seems to be gone in Chrome Version 35

/edit2

---

edit:

I had some trouble clarifying what exactly was the issue. But it is that any transformation after the path has been defined should not effect the path anymore, but that is what seems to be happening now. Clearing the stack for the 2nd time messes up the path that was already defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/HwLvU/4/

/edit

---

For the past 8 months I've been working on some drawing program that works great in all 5 major browsers. Well, until today.

To prevent scaling of line width I clear the transformation stack just before rendering and this has been working great and it still does, except in Chrome. Since today.

I'm wondering if there's something fundamentally wrong in what I'm doing or if it is just Chrome. The thing is that after the path has been created I should be able to do whatever I want with the transformation stack and it should not effect the position, scale or rotation of the path that was created.

The goal of what I'm trying to do is to have a fixed line width that is completely independent of the shape specific transformation.

```
// window specific transformation
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // clear stack
ctx.translate(300, 300);
ctx.scale(1, -1);

// shape specific transformation
ctx.transform(a, b, c, d, e, f);

createPathOfShape(ctx);

// prevent scaling of line width
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // clear stack

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: what is the issue with the latest Chrome ? line width is no longer of 1 ?

Comment: The issue is that any transformation after the path has been defined should not effect the path anymore, but that is what seems to be happening now. Clearing the stack for the 2nd time messes up the path that was already defined. I also changed the title.

Comment: maybe you could post 2 images (expected vs seen) to clarify things.

Comment: I've created a fiddle, see -> http://jsfiddle.net/HwLvU/4/

Comment: I had not done the latest update of Chrome on my computer : when i tested, it was working as expected. Then i updated, and the triangle was no longer to be seen on screen. See if it's not logged already, but you might file a bug for this.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that your fiddle behaves differently in the latest Chrome vs the latest IE & FF.

**Update: From the whatWG.org:** http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-paths-to-the-canvas

> 4.12.4.2.13 Drawing paths to the canvas
>
> The context always has a current default path. There is only one
>   current default path, it is not part of the drawing state
>
> When the intended path is the current default path, it is not affected
>   by the transform. (This is because transformations already affect the
>   current default path when it is constructed, so applying it when it is
>   painted as well would result in a double transformation.)

Comment: I should be able to add more paths with different transforms before I start drawing. For example try drawing a flower with ellipse arcs, you need a transfor for each leaf. If that's not possible, it would seriously cripple the power of the canvas.

Comment: with all due respect, markE, my understanding of the specs is just the opposite. "When the intended path is the current default path, it is not affected by the transform. " means, imho, that a new transform applied to an existing path won't change it. So it will just change the way it is drawn - the render part -. In fact, the part you quoted does not mention the influence of transform on path building vs rendering.

Comment: (i think 'current default path' would be more understandable as 'current path'. Maybe they used 'default' to emphasize the fact that some methods (like fillRect) do draw directly regardless of 'current default path')

Comment: They used "current default path" to be all the draws added to the context after the last beginPath (eg. context.lineTo).  The alternative to "current default path" will eventually be a new Path Object.  (The path object has not yet been implemented--except maybe in Chrome?)  You will eventually create a path object and will be able to fill that path with context.fill(myPathObject).  Reusable paths--cool, yes!  Even more cool when you can use path objects to test context.isPointInPath(myPathObject).

Comment: @GameAlchemist I think you might be right about the effect of a transform that's made after the path definition but before the fill/stroke.